# Cookie not changing to add SameSite attribute with PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, php-ini

I have a login form on my website to access certain links that I wrote in PHP. However, I am confused why I cannot set a SameSite cookie to secure my login form.

Here is my login form with the samesite cookie (everything else works fine)

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
session_name('__Secure-PHPSESSID');
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'Strict'); //line that is not working??
session_start();
```

Comment: Can you use Chrome DevTools or similar to share what the content of the `Set-Cookie` header is?

Comment: Yes, all I get is: `Set-Cookie: __Secure-PHPSESSID=doa4k9onoqpsnnfbg7ebt1bs3s; path=/; secure; HttpOnly` I never get the SameSite cookie working

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? `session.cookie_samesite` has only be available since PHP 7.3.0 - see the table on https://www.php.net/session.configuration